# Finding only pairs in list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Looking for a fancy one line solution to finding pairs of items in a list using list comprehension.

I've got some code that finds multiples, but can't figure out how to split those multiples into pairs.

```py
lst = [1,2,4,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,4,3,4,1]
len(set([x for x in lst if lst.count(x) > 1]))
```

Code above returns `4`. Answer should be `6` pairs, `[1,1,1,1,1] = 2`, `[2,2,2,2] = 2`, `[3,3,3] = 1` and `[4,4,4] = 1`.

Comment: Why for 1 and 2 there are 2 pairs while for 3 and 4 only 1?

Comment: Because [3 3 3] is one pair and a single value. [2,2,2,2] is an even double pair.

Comment: So, only looking for pairs of items in each sub-list. For example. [1,1] = 1, [1,1,1] = 1, [1,1,1,1] = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner with no other intermediate variables would be:

```
sum(lst.count(x)//2 for x in set(lst))
```

It loops over `set(lst)` which contains all the distinct numbers in `lst`, and adds their pair counts.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be using [[Python 3.Docs]: *class* collections.**Counter**(*[iterable-or-mapping]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> ```py
> >>> from collections import Counter
> >>>
> >>> lst = [1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1]
> >>>
> >>> c = Counter(lst)
> >>> c
> Counter({1: 5, 2: 4, 4: 3, 3: 3})
> >>>
> >>> sum(item // 2 for item in c.values())
> 6
> ```

and the one line equivalent:

> ```py
> >>> sum(item // 2 for item in Counter(lst).values())
> 6
> ```

Comment: Yeah. That was my original thought, but I wanted to avoid importing counter. It's another clean solution though.

Comment: The only sane answer here  (*O(n)*)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (if I've understood your pairing method properly):

```
lst = [1,2,4,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,4,3,4,1]
the_dict = {x: int((lst.count(x)/2)) for x in lst}

print(sum(the_dict.values()))

> 6

print(the_dict)

> {1: 2, 2: 2, 4: 1, 3: 1}
```

This makes a dictionary with the count of all pairs, then you can sum the values in the dictionary to get the pair count. Then you also have the dictionary available with the pair count of each value, if you need it.

Comment: This is great solution as well. I like how the dictionary can also give you the pairs.